# Asp.net Webforms Использование dropdownlist в gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms, gridview

Всем привет! Скорее всего, глупый вопрос, но не могу найти нормального ответа. В gridview при правке данных должен использоваться dropdownlist. Не могу сделать сохранение данных после выбора. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать. Заранее спасибо! Пока вот такой код:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="TasksGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="TasksEntityDataSource" DataKeyNames="task_ID">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Статус" SortExpression="task_status">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("task_status") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDropDownList" runat="server">
          <asp:ListItem>Не завершено</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>Завершено</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Изменяем код на:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="TasksGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="TasksEntityDataSource" DataKeyNames="task_ID" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="LightGray" OnRowUpdating="TasksGridView_RowUpdating">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Статус" SortExpression="task_status">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("task_status") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="StatusDropDownList" runat="server" OnInit="StatusDropDownList_Init">
          <asp:ListItem>Не завершено</asp:ListItem>
          <asp:ListItem>Завершено</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
      </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
```

И добавляем

```
        private DropDownList statusDropDownList;

    protected void StatusDropDownList_Init(object sendrer, EventArgs e)
    {
        statusDropDownList = sendrer as DropDownList;
    }
    protected void TasksGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        var tstatus = Convert.ToString(statusDropDownList.SelectedValue);
        e.NewValues["task_status"] = tstatus;
    }
```

После чего все работает!